# one download to update multiple macs

Tags: mac, updates

I have multiple macs, and some software updates are >1GB in size (e.g. iMovies). I have downloaded the standalone updater so that I can apply it across multiple machines, but when I attempt the installation it says that the software was purchased through the app store, and must be thus updated through the app store - this means that I have to download it 3 times for my 3 machines. This is not practical in countries with slow internet connections.

I am desperate to find a solution to this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two different solutions:

1. The easiest thing to do, instead of updating big apps in Software Update, go to apple.com/support/downloads and download the .pkg for the update in there. You can then save it to a flash drive and install it easily.
2. If you have a home OS X server of some sort, you can create a Software Update Sever. The SU Server downloads the update once and then the other machines download it from the server, instead of the Internet. The updates go a lot quicker that way.

Comment: Does this also work with updates distributed exclusively from the App Store? It seems the user already tried what you recommend in step 1.